# Django makemigrations doesn't generate migrations file

Tags: python, django-migrations

I'm running python manage.py makemigrations, and get an error of:
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

1. Create a project, and configure setting.py for MySQL info
2. Edit models.py in app
3. it pops the ValueError massege as above.

No idea where goes wrong.

Here are the traceback
[trackback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vh9GS.png)

Comment: Please attach the snippet of the code / traceback as well...

Comment: Updated the question with traceback screeshot, thanks!